# Capturing connection coming from outside in SQL server using profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I need to do testing on capturing connection coming from outside using Profiler. Can you please advise how I can do it.
I would really appreciate your help !

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on what "coming from outside" means and how/why it differs from normal operation of sql server profiler?

Comment: ok Thanks ! Basically I need to do something from other SQL servers connecting to this SQL server and test if it is captured by profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx

as the basics for SQL server profiler operation. To find queries in your situation - where the queries are originating from a different server - you can:

1. go into the profiler "Trace Properties" section
2. "Events Selection" tab
3. Column Filters
4. Login Name
5. Like [Enter the login that is being used to connect from the other server to this server] - this could be a domain account or a SQL server authentication account

Hopefully you're using separate accounts over your "normal" traffic and "outside" traffic, otherwise it could be difficult to filter out the noise.

I'm not sure about this one, but you might be also able to filter your profiler on "Host Name" (I haven't tried it personally however) - from the "Events Selection" tab, make sure the "Show all columns" checkbox is checked, go into the column filters and type in the machine name performing the queries under "Host Name"

Comment: Thank You so much Kritner ! However what kind of task can I perform in the source server pointing to this server to test this? Please help !

Comment: Well I think that depends on how the connection is done to the other server.  If you're hitting the other server say via a link, just open a connection on the "outside" server using the credentials you're profiling for, and do a `select * from [linkServer].[schema].[table]` - if you're profiling options are set up correctly you should see the query in your window.